# mysql update table column from a select statement with count

Tags: mysql, select, join, sql-update

I am working on some MySQL and am running into a bit of a problem.

I'm trying to update a column with the correct amount of credits taken by a student, but currently when I count the credits taken I get the total number of credits taken by all students. I

student table

```
ID  varchar(5)  
name    varchar(20) 
dept_name   varchar(20) 
tot_cred    decimal(3,0)
```

takes table

```
ID  varchar(5)  
course_id   varchar(8)  
sec_id  varchar(8)  
semester    varchar(6)  
year    decimal(4,0)    
grade   varchar(2)
```

course table

```
course_id   varchar(8)  
title   varchar(50) 
dept_name   varchar(20) 
credits decimal(2,0)
```

This is my statement that I'm currently using. I also have to add `if they have an f then they don't get credit for the class that they took`

```
update studentCopy set tot_cred = (
select sum(course.credits)
from student
left join takes on student.ID = takes.ID
left join course on takes.course_id = course.course_id
where student.ID = student.ID
group by studentCopy.ID);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simplifications to your query:

- The `left join`s are unnecessary.  You can just use `join`.
- The `group by` is unnecessary.  In fact, it is misleading, because it suggests that the subquery could return more than one row (which would generate an error).
- The `Student` table is unnecessary; you can write the correlation clause directory to `takes`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

So, I would write your query as:

```
update studentCopy sc
    set tot_cred = (select sum(c.credits)
                    from takes t join
                         course c
                         on t.course_id = c.course_id
                    where sc.ID = t.ID
                   );
```

You can add the condition on grades in the `where` clause:

```
update studentCopy sc
    set tot_cred = (select sum(c.credits)
                    from takes t join
                         course c
                         on t.course_id = c.course_id
                    where sc.ID = t.ID and grade <> 'f'
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got part of my answer just now. I changed

```
where student.ID = student.ID
```

to

```
where studentCopy.ID = student.ID
```

to give me the results of their own credits taken. Just working on getting the if grade = 'F' then don't count the grade.